# infragistics control create at code behind

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, infragistics, ignite-ui

i am new in infragistics control. now i creating different different control like grid,chart, map etc. there is required to create all control at code side and show in dashboard.here we can use xml file to set control position, theme, column header every thing should be different different based.

here we can create virtual table and show in dashboard.how can i create grid control and chart control at code side. please solve my problem.

i have tried create control at code side but we can not success for create control at code side.

thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by code side?  If you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 then I would assume that you are using the jQuery controls.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

There is help documents showing how to instantiate the Ignite UI components inside your MVC controllers and to return them as models to the view.

[igGrid MVC Guide](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2013.1/CLR4.0?page=igGrid_Developing_ASP_NET_MVC_Applications_with_igGrid.html)